# how to install autotest on linux?

Tags: linux, python

I'm looking at the autotest software suite found here:

https://github.com/autotest/autotest

I follow the instructions in the documentation here:

http://autotest.readthedocs.org/en/latest/main/local/ClientQuickStart.html

but when I use the command client/autotest-local --verbose run sleeptest as suggested in the documentation I get the following error:

```
18:39:05 ERROR| Can not find test sleeptest/control
```

So I'm guessing that part of the software is missing or not installed correctly yet I've followed the instructions. Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably because you are missing that test in `client/tests/sleeptest`.

Did you clone the repository with the `--recursive` option?

```
git clone --recursive git://github.com/autotest/autotest.git
cd autotest
client/autotest-local --verbose run sleeptest
```

That will initialize all the project submodules.

### Manual pages

From `git clone --help` or `man git-clone`:

```
--recursive, --recurse-submodules
    After the clone is created, initialize all submodules within, using
    their default settings. This is equivalent to running git submodule
    update --init --recursive immediately after the clone is finished.
    This option is ignored if the cloned repository does not have a
    worktree/checkout (i.e. if any of --no-checkout/-n, --bare, or
    --mirror is given)
```

Comment: the corporate firewall was blocking GIT from running correctly and was only downloading certain things before cutting the connect but your answer pushed me i the right direction thank you